# Retrieving a deployed contract with a different MetaMask address

Tags: remix, contract-deployment

Earlier I deployed a contract with a MetaMask address 0xAAA, and got the contract address.

In a new instance of Remix, I have the exact same code source, and would like to retrieve the contract from another MetaMask address 0xBBB.

So I did:

- I set Injected Web3, like I did earlier to deploy.
- I got the same source code I used to deploy with 0xAAA, compiled.
- I have my MetaMask set with address 0xBBB, but with the same network I used to deploy.
- I added the contract address in the field: At Address, but the button stays greyed.

Do I miss something? My goal is to test my contract from the point of view of a regular user.

Comment: Looks like you're doing everything just right. Make sure that the contract address is in fact valid address. Also it happens to me sometimes that if I fill in the address first and then configure other things, it stays greyed out. Try to refill the address box again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply fixed the problem by refreshing Remix tab in my browser.

Sometimes Remix doesn't work well after the computer wakes up from sleep.